# dns_sd.h not found in windows

Tags: bonjour

I am doing a qt application for bonjour advertising..so i need to use dns_sd library for that.can anyone let me know where i can find that library or ddl or dns_sd.h file..when i compile my program i get an error "dns_sd.h no such file"(I am working under windows)

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to that file from Google...

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-58.5/mDNSShared/

Not sure if that's what you need or not.